# Storing masks in jpg format

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-recognition

I've created masks(numpy array with 0,1 as values) and tried exporting this array to jpg using matplolib but it's not exporting the values as it is. I'm getting a range of pixel values in resulting image. Is there any way in which I can add the array values to pixel values as it is. For example numpy array is 40X40 and resulting jpg image resolution is 40X40 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

When you simply use say plt.savefig() to jpg, matplotlib by default does not save it to a binary image as you require. JPG by default the definition is values ranging from 0-255. 
Suggest using PIL instead of matplotlib then you can save as BW binary image.

Comment: What if I have multiple classes like 0,1,2,3,4,5, etc?

Comment: For my problem mask has values 1.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5.

Comment: Having multiple classes is possible. You can force the rescaling not to happen while saving.